# Why JavaScript function's toString method is called many times when debugging step by step in Chrome DevTool?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

## Test environment:

- MacOS v10.14.6;
- Chrome 89.0.4389.82

## Question description:

I added a breakpoint in `toString` method of a function and debug it step by step, I see that the `toString` method is called when I step to the next line.

It is a little hard to describe it in language, please watch the screen recording：[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gOnrzc9xS3E)

Why?

## Code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    function fn() { }

    fn.toString = function () {
      debugger;
      console.log('toString called');
      const a = 'a';
      return a;
    };

    fn.toString();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's just like that when using some IDE to debug a program. The dev tool **shows the value of a variable by calling its `toString` function**. When I am debugging a Java program in IDEA, it also works like that.

Comment: I don't understand how this explains why the `console.log` is called multiple times despite having the `debugger` before it. Just to give you an idea, if you move `toString()` outside of the `fn()`. function. The log doesn't happen multiple times